# UINavigationController with unified background across all ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've been toying around with an idea of a `UINavigationController` that has an image as background and every view controller on the stack would have transparent background so the background image of the `UINavigationController` is visible across all of them.

I tried implementing this the most obvious way (have root view controller with fullscreen image and view controllers with transparent background, but this results in awkward issues with animation).

Digging around I found HotelTonight app managed to implement this. See a recording of their user interface. I made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvynwhCj5oM&list=UUKnxsyMsRRRJs_Yw9GZVOFw

Does anybody have some suggestion on a right path implementing this?

Comment: your video is hidden.

Comment: Apologies, iMovie set it as hidden. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to subclass UIViewController to have a particular setup for its background and navigation controller style. For example, in the viewDidLoad method of your UIViewController subclass, set its background to a certain image. You can also use this to style your navigation bar (certain colors for the barButtonItems, etc). Then each new view controller you create is a subclass of your skinned view controller.

If your background is an image, you will still get the weird animation effects when a new view controller slides in over the top of the old one; the background will slide in as well. Depending on how custom you want to make your transition animations, there are things you can do to play around with the views during the transition. UIPresentationController might present some solutions for making a more custom animated transition.

Edit: To emulate the Hotel now app, I made a UINavigationController with an image as a background, and controllers on top with clear backgrounds. On a push, I animate the alpha of the first controller to 0 while the segue is happening. On returning, I set the alpha back to 1.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view.alpha = 1;
}

-(void)didClickButton:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
        self.view.alpha = 0;
    }];

    // the transition itself is a push segue defined in the storyboard
}
```

I believe that the Hotel App's background works well with this method since it's very dark. Not sure if it would be very effective for brighter apps or apps with a lot of content in the controller being covered.

Comment: What you described won't achieve what i was talking about. See the video. I need to have one static background across all view controllers on the stack.

Comment: after clicking back and forth a bunch of times on my hotel now app, i see two things: 1) I think the content of the first controller is being faded out and back in very quickly. 2) I actually see a shadow of the first screen briefly as the second comes through. So I believe that they are fading out the content of the first screen while pushing the second screen onto the stack. I was able to replicate this by doing an animated alpha fade on the controller that was pushing a new controller.